# I am not able to see push notifications in notification bar/panel I am using phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: javascript, php, android, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I am not able to see push notifications in notification bar/panel I am using https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push .However, I am receiving the messages sent from my php server (its showing in the alert).Can anyone please tell me why do not I see the notifications in the notification bar in android?

Here is my java script code in the index.html.

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            "senderID": "111111111111"
        },
        "ios": {}, 
        "windows": {} 
    });

    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        //alert("registration event");
        //document.getElementById("regId").innerHTML = data.registrationId;
        //alert(data.registrationId);
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        var url = 'http://mywebsite.com/reest/rest2.php?id='+data.registrationId;
                   // alert(url);
                     $.post( url, function( data ) {
//alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});

    });

    push.on('notification', function(data) {
        alert("notification event");
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        var cards = document.getElementById("cards");
        var push = '<div class="row">' +
              '<div class="col s12 m6">' +
              '  <div class="card darken-1">' +
              '    <div class="card-content black-text">' +
              '      <span class="card-title black-text">' + data.title + '</span>' +
              '      <p>' + data.message + '</p>' +
              '    </div>' +
              '  </div>' +
              ' </div>' +
              '</div>';
        cards.innerHTML += push;
    });

    push.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("push error");
    });
}
};

app.initialize();
```

And here below is my php code to send the gcm message from the my server

```
<?php


//------------------------------
// Payload data you want to send 
// to Android device (will be
// accessible via intent extras)
//------------------------------

$data = array( message => 'Hello World! i am app',title => 'Large Icon');

//------------------------------
// The recipient registration IDs
// that will receive the push
// (Should be stored in your DB)
// 
// Read about it here:
// http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/
//------------------------------

$ids = array( $_GET['id'] );//array( 'abc', 'def' );

//------------------------------
// Call our custom GCM function
//------------------------------

sendGoogleCloudMessage(  $data, $ids );

//------------------------------
// Define custom GCM function
//------------------------------

function sendGoogleCloudMessage( $data, $ids )
{
//------------------------------
// Replace with real GCM API 
// key from Google APIs Console
// 
// https://code.google.com/apis/console/
//------------------------------

$apiKey = 'apikeyhere';

//------------------------------
// Define URL to GCM endpoint
//------------------------------

$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

//------------------------------
// Set GCM post variables
// (Device IDs and push payload)
//------------------------------

$post = array(
                'registration_ids'  => $ids,
                'data'              => $data,
                );

//------------------------------
// Set CURL request headers
// (Authentication and type)
//------------------------------

$headers = array( 
                    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );

//------------------------------
// Initialize curl handle
//------------------------------

$ch = curl_init();

//------------------------------
// Set URL to GCM endpoint
//------------------------------

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

//------------------------------
// Set request method to POST
//------------------------------

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

//------------------------------
// Set our custom headers
//------------------------------

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

//------------------------------
// Get the response back as 
// string instead of printing it
//------------------------------

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

//------------------------------
// Set post data as JSON
//------------------------------

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $post ) );

//------------------------------
// Actually send the push!
//------------------------------

$result = curl_exec( $ch );

//------------------------------
// Error? Display it!
//------------------------------

if ( curl_errno( $ch ) )
{
    echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
}

//------------------------------
// Close curl handle
//------------------------------

curl_close( $ch );

//------------------------------
// Debug GCM response
//------------------------------

echo $result;
}
```